# Fragment Default View Wont Change

Tags: android, fragment

i really need help.

This is how my application looks like. I got two(2) fragments where the left side is for the buttons and for the right side is for my details.
The bigger fragment has a default display which i called splash. An image is viewed here, a bigger image that would take the height of the device.

So my case is when i click/press button 1, it would display the fragment for that but the image is still present.
My question now is, how to i get rid of the 'splash display'?

Here is my code

```
/**
 * on main listener
 */
@Override
public void onMainListener(String whatPress){
    Fragment fr = null;

     if(whatPress.equals("button1"))
         fr = new FragmentOne();
     if(whatPress.equals("button2"))
         fr = new FragmentTwo();
     if(whatPress.equals("button3"))
         fr = new FragmentThree();

     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, fr, whatPress);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

The code above is the one handles which button is pressed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
    android:name="FragmentMenu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.mizsh.Fragment_Menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
    android:name="com.mizsh.Fragment_Splash"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code above is my main.xml

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the `detailFragment` with `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/detailFragment" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and replace it with `Fragment_Splash` in the `onCreate` of the activity

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, fragmentSplash, null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

then replace with chosen fragment on click

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, chosenFragment, null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```